# Set line width in OpenGL 3 / GLSL 130

Tags: opengl, glsl, opengl-3

I'm using a scene where wireframes are shown and where I want to set the width of the used lines to 2.

When I search for this problem, I only stumble upon `glLineWidth()`-function which seems to belong to old OpenGL 1.x

So: how can I set the width of wireframe lines when OpenGL3 / GLSL 130 is used?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Line width was never *removed* from OpenGL. It was deprecated, but in 3.1, when most of the deprecated features were removed, line width was not among them. So there's no reason you shouldn't be able to use it in OpenGL 3.1+ core profile.

Just don't create a "[forward compatibility context](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/OpenGL_Context#Forward_compatibility)", and you should be fine. Now yes, MacOS's OpenGL support doesn't let you create a 3.1+ context unless you declare it to be forward compatible. But MacOS deprecated *OpenGL* as a whole, so how long the API will be supported on that platform is unclear.

Comment: About MacOS and forward compatible context, I think this is a `glfw` issue, Many glfw pages tell it's MacOS requirement [see e.g. this](https://github.com/glfw/glfw/issues/904). But [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsopenglpixelformat#1653758) have not defined the proper flag.

Comment: @Ripi2: I'd believe the report of an actual bug over what documentation says. The former is reproducible.

Comment: I don't have a Mac to test it, but are you saying that creating a Core profile just with OSX API (no glfw or whatever) creates a forward compatible context?

Comment: @Ripi2: I personally don't know exactly how it works. It could be that you have to specify the forward-compatibility flag to create a core profile in OSX. It could be that asking for a core profile automatically gives you a forward-compatibility context. Either way, the result is the same: OSX does not support `glLineWidth` in a core profile.